# Como omitir tamanho de matriz de char na função?

Tags: c++, matriz, char

Me apareceu uma dúvida agora, tenho uma função implementada desta maneira:

```
mostrarMensagem(char msg[10])
{
//aqui faço algo com a variável "msg".
}
```

porém eu não sei o tamanho que irei receber como parâmetro real, se for maior que 10 não funcionará como esperado, o parâmetro passado para a função poderá ser assim:

```
mostrarMensagem("ola");
```

ou assim:

```
mostrarMensagem("ola156186485348545215554548843456etc");
```

Então precisaria não passar o tamanho inicial da matriz de char, estou pensando, consegui imaginar algo, mas creio que será muito trabalho desenvolver o que quer surgir na minha mente, existe alguma maneira "rápida" de fazer isso em c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja bem o nome da string representa um ponteiro para a primeira posicao e a linguagem c/c++ considera tudo que encontra pela frente como parte da string , ou no caso de um vetor de char "char str[N]" ela tera N caracteres , assim sendo uma funcao que recebe uma string como parametro recebera simplemente um ponteiro para a primeira posicao do vetor - todas as funcoes da biblioteca string fazem isso .

Exemplo - bem simples:

```
void printString(char* strRecebida)/*não sabedo a tamanho da string voce pode usar este recurso de "char*" */
{
  printf("Sua string : %s",strRecebida);
}
```

CUIDADO : Strings em c são passadas por referencia , ou seja , não altere essa string dentro da funcao. :wacko: Exemplo - um pouco mais complicado:

```
void alterarString(char* strRecebida)
{
  strcpy(strRecebida,"ESTRAGUEI");
}
int main
{
  char str[20]="MINHA STRING";
  printf("Minha string: %s",str);/*IMPRIMIRA : Minha string : MINHA STRING*/
  alterarString(str);
  printf("Minha string alterada: %s",str);/*IMPRIMIRA Minha string alterada : ESTRAGUEI*/
}
```

para evitar esse problema deve-se colocar "const" :ninja: no prototipo da funcao

void alterarString(const char* strRecebida)

ai o compilador avisara se você tentar alterar algo na string dentro da funcao

Espero ter ajudado, acho que me empolguei um pouco.

Comment: Ajudou sim, tinha feito já, mas ajudou a melhorar o que tinha feito aqui, estava usando <string>, e utilizando char stg* para pegar a string, e nem pensei em ir direto com o ponteiro no parâmetro, agradeço.

Comment: estou recebendo esse erro ao compilar: ` undefined reference to `MinhaClasse::MinhaFuncao(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) `

Comment: Tudo certo, dei um clean nos arquivos-objetos aqui, era um arquivo-objeto.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, você pode fazer isso de duas formas.

A primeira delas é utilizar a notação de vetor dentro dos parâmetros da função:

```
mostrarMensagem(char msg[])
{
   cout << msg;
}

mostrarMensagem("oi");
```

Nesse caso a função mostrarMensagem recebe como argumento um array de char, não importando o tamanho do array.

A segunda forma é utilizando a notação de ponteiros:

```
mostrarMensagem(char * msg)
{
   cout << msg;
}

mostrarMensagem("oi");
```

Nesses dois casos a função mostrarMensagem espera como argumento um ponteiro para um char, pois quando você usa `char msg[]` como parâmetro da função é equivalente a usar `char * msg`.

Uma vez que o ponteiro para char recebido pela função armazena o endereço da memória do primeiro caractere da "string", os demais caracteres estarão nas posições da memória subsequentes a esse ponteiro até um limite que é o tamanho da "string", podemos usar aritmética de ponteiros para exibir o array inteiro começando da posição `*(msg + 0)` enquanto `*(msg + i) != '\0'` que indica o término da "string":

```
mostrarMensagem(char * msg)
    {
       int i = 0;

       while(*(msg + i) != '\0') {
          cout << *(msg + i);
          i++;
       }
 }

mostrarMensagem("ola156186485348545215554548843456etc");
```

similarmente, podemos usar a notação de array que estamos mais habituados que, nesse caso, dará no mesmo:

```
mostrarMensagem(char * msg)
{
   int i = 0;

   while(msg[i] != '\0') {
      cout << msg[i];
      i++;
   }
 }

mostrarMensagem("ola156186485348545215554548843456etc");
```

Comment: Muito bom, valeu.